# How to calculate voltage from A0 pin

Tags: arduino-uno, electronics

I would like to calculate the amount of voltage from my A0 pin. I am using a 9v battery to power my load in my circuit. The formula to calculate voltage from the A0 pin is:

```
    sens = analogRead(A0);
    vol = sens * ( 5.0 / 1023.0);
```

If my power source is 9v, should i replace the 5.0 to 9.0?

Comment: The formula is `sens * ( 5.0 / 1024.0)`, not 1023. C.f. the datasheet of the microcontroller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The analog input pins are 0V-5V strictly. If you need to measure a 9V input, you need to scale the voltage to test so that it is within a 0V-5V range. Often this is done with a voltage divider circuit.

In the example below, the 9V test voltage is divided in half, so the scale is 0V-4.5V, which is within range of the input pin.

Then your algorithm is

```
vol = sens * (2.0) * ( 5.0 / 1024.0);
```

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmTaiH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Per the datasheet of the microcontroller: 1) The scaling factor is 1024, not 1023. 2) The resistors should be no more than 20 kΩ.

Comment: Updated the answer. Was trying to keep leakage current low, but you're right, 100k+100k is too high to get enough current for a reliable reading.